# How to enable schedule in java spring boot

Tags: java, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have used to java Scheduled cron to set auto job in my project.
I add config in main SpringBootApplication, and job class, but nothing happen, job doesn't run every time which i set (10 seconds).
So how can i fix it?

This is main start.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class RabbitMqPublishSubscribeApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RabbitMqPublishSubscribeApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

And this is my job

```
@Component
public class SchedulerConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private RabbitMqJobs jobs;

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")  
        public void schedulePutQueue() {
            try {
                System.out.println("BEGIN JOB SIGN");           
                jobs.putDataToQueue();
    
            } catch(Exception e) {          
                ReportLogger.logger.error("Exception main:" +e.getStackTrace().toString(),e);
            }catch (Error er) {
                ReportLogger.logger.error("Error main:" +er.getStackTrace().toString(),er);
            } 
            
        }
}
```

Comment: The `schedulePutQueue` method needs to be on a Spring component

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Other project i only config like that, and everything run ok. But this project doesn't.

Comment: Your initial question didn't make it clear that you had the method on a component -- your edit does, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Have you done some debugging -- e.g. checking that `SchedulerConfiguration` is being created and using a simple trigger for the task instead of a cron expression?

Comment: I think you can check if your `SchedulerConfiguration` is initiated yet, e.g. using `@PostConstruct` and print something out.

Comment: I run method from other class ok. But when merge with job schedule it doesn't run.
I also try other way, used TimerTask, but it conflict with @RabbitListener which i using.

Answer (score 0):

What's the package location of this class "SchedulerConfiguration"? It should be in sub-directory of package name of RabbitMqPublishSubscribeApp class. Could you please double check this?

Comment: Thanks for support. I moved class file in same package, and now job run completed.